# When performing a replaceWith via Ajax, the html of the fields is not being replaced correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, replace

Before submitting with Ajax, I am changing the ids of all inputs on the form, due to a need.

[image: Image 1]

The problem is when I submit using Ajax, I need to replace the html of all fields in the form using the replaceWith function, but it is not doing that. It is simply changing the html, but it seems to be keeping the original html when I inspect it in the browser.
HTML should be replaced as shown in image 2.

[image: Image 2]

Why can't HTML be replaced correctly? Shouldn't the replaceWith function be used for such a situation?

```
var genericModal = getLastGenericModalObject();
var frmFormaContato = genericModal.find('.frm-create-edit');
var valdata = frmFormaContato.serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    data: valdata,
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    success: function (data) {


        frmFormaContato.replaceWith(data);

        

        stopLoadGlobal();
    },
    error: function (e) {
        stopLoadGlobal();

        redirectToError(e.status);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Thank you :)

Comment: what is getLastGenericModalObject and data?

Comment: It is a function that takes the instance of the modal Bootstrap window.

Comment: Changing the DOM doesn't change the original HTML source. You can see the changes in the Elements panel, but not in View Source.

Comment: Wow, this is really bad, for me, because I need to keep the field ids up to date. If the DOM is in a different way and the HTML in another, besides being confused, it would bring problems. Isn't there a way to make the replace 100% faithful?

Comment: Hi @Jalber, why do you want to replace this dom? Could you please share more html code and explain your scenario?

Comment: Hi @Rena! 
In my case, I am working with modal bootstrap windows and I need to control the field IDs so that there is no duplication when opening the same window more than once. The problem is that when I use replaceWith and replace the html, the DOM is out of date. I believe that the most practical solution will be to change the IDs in the data variable and replace the html ... Thus, the DOM will be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the IDs before replacing the HTML according to the DOM.

```
var dataChanged = changeIds($(data));

frmFormaContato.replaceWith(dataChanged);
```